# Furnace limit switch only reading 12 volts, I have 24 volts coming out of transformer

Tags: hvac

12 volts at primary limit switch, 24 volts out at transformer 24 volts at c & w terminals when stat calling for heat. furnace will not light, trouble codes call for bad primary/secondary limit switch

Comment: What make and model is the furnace?

Comment: lennox  merit series  model g40uh-36b-090-07

Comment: Is that 12V from a limit switch terminal to ground, or 12V across the limit switch?

Comment: 12V from limit switch to ground, on each side of limit switch, 0V across limit switch.

Comment: also when disconnected limit switch has continuity,  (not open)

Comment: Is there 12 or 24V from each terminal of the *secondary* limit switch to ground?

Comment: So I turned everything off to reset the system, put my meters on the limit switches then turned the power on. It went  through the startup tests all the way to heating up the igniter, at which time I had 24 volts at both the primary and secondary limit switches, with the igniter red hot the gas valve never opened, when the igniter shut down the voltage at the limit switches dropped and bounced from 7.8V to 12.2V and diagnostic lights started flashing the limit switch open code.

Comment: Does the voltage at the W terminal start sagging as well once the igniter is fully heated?

Comment: tested gas valve by putting 24V to the terminals, the valve opened and I heard gas flow and smelled it

Comment: no voltage at the W terminal remains constant at 24V